# Troubleshooting 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server' connecting to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, ef-core-2.2

**Background**:

I've created a .Net Core (2.2.0) application using EFCore (2.2.2). Up until now I have been using a local SQL Server instance and am attempting to use an Azure SQL Server instead.

I have updated the connection string in the database context to that found on the Azure dashboard.

I have signed in to the account used in Azure within the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS2017, and the database is appearing.

I'm using a code-first approach so there are no tables available, until after running the application.

**Error**:

> A network-related or 
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
>   The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

The connection string is:

```
.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server = tcp:db.database.windows.net, 1433;
              Initial Catalog = DB;
              Persist Security Info = False;
              User ID = username@db.database.windows.net;
              Password = password; 
              MultipleActiveResultSets = False; Encrypt = True; 
              TrustServerCertificate = false; 
              Connection Timeout = 60;");
```

My local network hasn't got fantastic capabilities. Could this have an effect on connecting?

Or is there an error in this connection string?

Edit: I changed the connection timeout to 800 seconds, after a period of ~800 seconds the connection timed out again, this time with a slightly different error:

**Error 2**:

> A network-related or 
>   'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)'

Comment: I can't say for sure what you have is wrong, but I've personally never seen the server declared that way. What happens if you just use `Server=db.database.windows.net:1433;`? Or actually, you can leave the port off as well, since 1433 is the default. TCP is also the default. That's what all HTTP communication uses.

Comment: It's returning the same error with that way. I copied the connection string from the Azure properties page, that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Are you connecting from within your organization network or outisde? Just trying to rule out network traversal/latency issues.

Comment: No it's a home network. I have the connection string timeout set to 800 seconds. If the error is thrown in and around 800 seconds after starting the connection, do you think that would be an indicator of latency issues? 13 minutes seems like plenty of time to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close this as it turned out to be a latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have provided rights to your Azure database to be connected remotely from security group. Mostly it is not allowed to be accessed from remote computer. check from DB Security Group and Resource security group and Make sure your IP is in allowed list.

Comment: When I connected to the server on VS Azure verified that I was allowed to connect from my local IP. How would I check these on the Azure portal?

Comment: Go to portal.azure.com -> Resources -> SQL Database -> select your Database -> Set Server Firewall -> Connections from the IPs specified below provides access to all the databases in db ->  Here your IP should be there in allow list

Comment: Also allow access to Azure services ON

Comment: Yeah my IP is listed here. I think the connection to VS added it.

Comment: are you able to connect it from SSMS ?

Comment: I haven't got access to SSMS at the minute, however I can connect through Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer.

Comment: Server=tcp:domainname.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: make sure you typing tcp:servername property and not dbname.database. You can find the same under portal.azure.com -> Resources -> SQL Database ->  Connection strings

Comment: and also you have download connection driver if required from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download